# Create VideoFrame from YUV 4:2:0 data

Tags: android, webrtc-android

I want to create a CustomVideoCapturer, which will convert YUV4:2:0 data buffer to VideoFrame then send data via webrtc.

But current example use Camera as VideoCapturer source, I do not find any help sample to do such convert.

I can find a [YuvConverter.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/HEAD/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/YuvConverter.java), but it's for TextureSurface to I420Buffer converter. it's not used for YUV data buffer.

Can anyone help direct me to implement that function?

Comment: Don't know too much about WebRTC, but can't you just concatenate the results from `I420Buffer.getDataY()getDataU()/getDataV()`?

Comment: Any update on this?